# Unpivot Matrix to Tabular. Using counts of two variables into individual rows

Tags: google-sheets

I have a basic register format, Matrix format, names in first column and dates across the top row.

A2:A20 Names (Range changes on class size)

B1:E1 Dates (Range changes)

A2:E20 = Counts numeric: (1 to 5)

I would like to convert this into a tabular format, unpivot the results considering the counts.

So if **Name 1** attends twice in on **Day 1** and **Name 2** Attended once on **Day 2** and **Name 3** attend 5 times on **Day 3**: the output would show:

Row1:n1, d1

Row2:n1, d1

Row3:n2, d2

Row3:n3, d3

Row3:n3, d3

Row3:n3, d3

Row3:n3, d3

Row3:n3, d3

Could anyone help me with this? Will this work on Google Sheets?

Comment: Best to pick one platform...

Comment: apologise, it's my first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Google Sheets solution:

`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(REPT(A2:A20&", "&B1:E1&"  ",B2:E20),,100)),,100),"  ",0))))`

The `REPT` forms a string for each value *n* in the matrix that is a repetition of comma-separated name and day, *n* times. The inner `QUERY` is a trick to robustly concatenate each column, space-separated. The 100 just needs to be a value that you know exceeds the number of rows in the matrix.

`TRANSPOSE` makes the resultant array vertical, and the outer `QUERY` again concatenates this array, space-separated (the 100 needs to exceed the number of columns in the source matrix, in this case).

You end up with one string, with the name-date pairs separated by at least two spaces in a row. The `SPLIT` breaks apart the string by those double-spaces, and `TRIM` gets rid of unwanted spaces at either end of the resulting strings. The outer `TRANSPOSE` makes the output vertical.

Comment: This works really well for Google Sheets! Explanation is also very useful.