# Count unique cells and display them in column

Tags: google-sheets, data-analysis

I am building a list of gigs I attended and I want to count how many times I've seen each band.

I know about `UNIQUE`, but because I keep each band in separate column it just copies each row.

Given the table [(or screenshot of real data):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyPsR.png)

```
|   Date   | Venue  |                   Bands                    |
|----------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| 02.02.17 | Venue1 | Band A | Band B | Band C | Band D | Band E |
| 02.07.17 | Venue3 | Band D | Band C |        |        |        |
```

The output I want:

```
|  Band  | Attended |
|        | (times)  |
|--------|----------|
| Band A |        1 |
| Band B |        1 |
| Band C |        2 |
| Band D |        2 |
| Band E |        1 |
```

I can change structure if needed.

What happens after using `UNIQUE`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmszk.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @pnuts To be honest I have no idea what you are talking about, except for accessibility of image, to which I agree. However keep in mind that this is a rather simple task, I am not into spreadsheets and this thing is just for me, so please there's no need to be so harsh.

Comment: Can you make a expected output screenshot. You could do this with JOIN/SPLIT combo.

Comment: If you just want COUNT,Use COUNTUNIQUE()

Comment: @I'-'I I don't want to only count... I need to do unique band - count per row, for example: Band 1 - 10 Band 2 - 5 Band 3 - 12
I've updated the question so you can see what output I'd like to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. Get list of all unique bands in one column, one per row
`=ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(Gigs!D2:Z&CHAR(9)); CHAR(9)))))`

Step 2. Place this formula in next column, and drag it down

`=SUM(COUNTIF(Gigs!D:Z; E2))`

Comment: `=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("⚓",1,Gigs!D2:Z),"⚓")) ,"Select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1",0)`

Comment: @I'-'I I don't know what do you mean, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Transform your data to a *simple table* format in order to make easier to do [data-analysis](/questions/tagged/data-analysis).

A simple table use the first row for column headers a.k.a. fields and has one and only one column for each entity, let say only one column for band names.

The above could be done in a single but complex formula hard to debug, so it's better to start by doing this using simple formulas and once you are certain that all is working fine, think about making a complex formula or writing and script.

Related

- [Unpivot Matrix to Tabular. Using counts of two variables into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31815226/1595451)
- [Generate a list of all unique values of a multi-column range and give the values a rating according to how many times they appear in the last X cols](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38563939/1595451)
- [Normalize (reformat) cross-tab data for Tableau without using Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27808282/1595451)
- [How do you create a "reverse pivot" in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24954722/1595451)